# How to install typings of discord.js for typescript?

Tags: node.js, typescript, discord.js

Im new to typescript, I found out that to use the npm packages, I first need to install its typings for it such as

```
npm install --save @types/node-schedule
```

however im using discord.js too, but this doesnt work

```
import * as Discord from 'discord.js';
```

then

```
npm install --save @types/discord.js

npm ERR! code E404
npm ERR! 404 Not Found - GET https://registry.npmjs.org/@types%2fdiscord.js - Not found
npm ERR! 404
npm ERR! 404  '@types/discord.js@latest' is not in the npm registry.
npm ERR! 404 You should bug the author to publish it (or use the name yourself!)
npm ERR! 404
npm ERR! 404 Note that you can also install from a
npm ERR! 404 tarball, folder, http url, or git url.
```

how can I fix this?

Comment: The package name is `discord.js`, not `@types/discord.js`. You only need typings when using javascript libraries or otherwise libraries that do not include type information.

Answer (score 5):

`@types\package` used for those packages that don't provide types themself. If you open the discord.js package.json [file](https://github.com/discordjs/discord.js/blob/master/package.json), you will find this line  `"types": "./typings/index.d.ts",`. This means that types already included in the main package and you don't need additional installation.

So, firstly install the main package and if TSC will start complaining about the missing types, search for the types. Also, sometimes, you might spot that type missing in @types as well. In this case, you will have to write your own typing. Luckily this is a more-less rear case.